# Queue Triggered Azure Function not always logging

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have two Azure functions in a solution that I am building.  The first is a webhook, that simply takes a payload does some validation and puts a payload on a queue.  The second function has a QueueTrigger that reads from that queue and processes the message.  The solution seems to be working fine, all of the incoming messages are processed fine.  The issue that I am seeing is around logging.  For some reason, all of the invocations of the QueueTrigger don't add a log to the monitor tab of the function.  For instance, I have 13 invocations of the webhook today, and should have a corresponding number of invocations of the queue trigger, however I only have 5 logged invocations.  There are also times where I see the logs that should be in the queue trigger function, embedded in the webhooks logs.  Do you know what may be causing this?

Here is the basic code in the function:

```cs
    public static class UpdateQueueProcessor
    {
        [FunctionName("UpdateQueueProcessor")]
        public static async void Run([QueueTrigger("updates", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Queue Processor Invoked: {myQueueItem}");

                //convert the queue payload to an object
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebhooksData>(myQueueItem);

                //retrieve what quickbooks environment to target
                var qbEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment");

                var refreshService = new RefreshService();
                refreshService.Logger = log;

                log.LogInformation($"Environment:  {qbEnv}");

                foreach(var x in data.EventNotifications)
                {
                    log.LogInformation($"Invoking Update");
                    await refreshService.Update(x);
                    log.LogInformation($"Update Complete");
                };
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"An error has occurred:  {ex.Message + " " + (ex.InnerException == null ? "" : ex.InnerException.Message)}");

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is some delay could it be that its less than 30 minutes?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  The last job ran 5 hours ago.

Comment: Are you sure there were 13 messages put in the queue? Can you check is they didn't throw an exception and are put on your queue-poison?

Comment: Yeah, there were definitely 13 messages put on the queue.  I have logging around the webhook and that part looks fine.  The vast majority of the queue processor invocation logging appears to go into the webhook logs for some reason, even though they are different functions.  Sometimes they go into their own logs, and i'm missing a couple logs altogether.

Comment: @Dennis Can you share your code for the function that is triggered on QueueTrigger?

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge Yes, I just updated the question with the code snippet from the function.

Comment: @Dennis All looks ok... The only thing that eventually could be happening would be that the logInformation inside the catch would throw an error... Maybe you can debug by forcing an exception and checking if that log runs properly. Besides that only an azure bug.

Comment: I don't know if this would affect the logging, but the `async void` is wrong. That should be `async Task`.

Comment: Maybe this is caused by data-sampling rate (depending on configuration this will drop log messages). I am assuming you are using Application Insights to look at your logs.

Comment: @Daniel . That's interesting.  I don't think that's the issue here since this is still in development and receiving very few invocations, but I guess I didn't realize that Applications Insights only samples data.  I assumed that it logged every invocation.

Comment: Check the host.json file and set App Insights sampling to false.